# Where does setup.py install data files inside a virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I've found multiple sources (https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute, http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/, http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/06/25/python-packaging-pitfalls/) that suggest that the way to distribute data files in a Python package is to use setuptools's `include_package_data` option and a `MANIFEST.in`.  The files in my package thus look like,

`setup.py`

`setup(
    # ...
    include_package_data = True,
    # ...`

with the rest of the file (hopefully irrelevant) elided.

`MANIFEST.IN`

`graft testdata
include ChangeLog
include README.rst
include COPYING
include COPYING.LESSER
include tox.ini`

When I run `setup.py install` or use pip in a virtualenv, I end up with the Python source files themselves, but without `testdata/` anywhere I can find it.  I'd think this was an error in my packaging, except that when I grab another package with a similar layout, I can't find the data files either.  If I clone the repository for the example package https://github.com/ionelmc/python-nameless and install it using `setup.py install`, the package installs in the directory `lib/python3.4/site-packages/nameless-0.1.0-py3.4.egg/nameless/`.  However, I can't find any of the data files or tests anywhere in the virtualenv.  Where are they supposed to end up?  How is this supposed to work?

My motivation for asking this question is that another contributor on a project wants the tests, which require the data files, to run from a pip install.  Is this the right approach in the first place?

Comment: Use `pkg_resources` to discover your data files. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34788912/3626079) for similar question.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you should just

`include testdata`

instead of `graft`ing it - to be honest, I am actually not sure what `graft` does.

Also I do not believe it is required to specify `include_package_data = True` at all

Comment: `include` includes files matching the pattern, not directories.  As far as I know, this is only explained in the legacy documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/commandref.html .  (If it's explained in the non-legacy documentation, I have no idea where.)  `graft` includes entire directories.  In both my MANIFEST.in and the example package's, `include` is used for individual files, and I can't find those files in the virtualenv either.  I've tried `recursive-include` on `testdata/` as well, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue yesterday. Previously I was manually storing COPYING and LICENCE in `/etc/nepi` but that was breaking under virtualenv. Now (see [my git repo here](http://git.onelab.eu/?p=nepi.git;a=tree)) things run just fine. If you don't see any of the files included, I suspect something else is going wrong. Also I have seen examples of `include` being used with a directory but have no evidence that it would work. I agree that the documentation on this is not exactly clear :)